# How to draw a plot like this using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I need to draw a plot like the image below but I don't know what it's called or if any of the libraries such as `matplotlib` or `plotly` support it.

The x-axis shows a set of classes and the y-axis is the values predicted for samples of that class using some classifier.[image]

Comment: you should add your data sample as well

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html

Comment: @Poppinyoshi I don't think there is any need for that. The example shows the format clearly.

Comment: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html

Comment: @DarthPaghius see you have recommendations for three different kinds of plots in the comments. That's why I asked for data sample. Either way is fine I guess. Now you can choose.